# jquery ui autocomplete with json object doesn't work

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am trying to use a JSON object with jquery ui autocomplete. Not having much success. I looked at https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data. But the example has too much superfluous code which I don't need. Anyway, the json object doesn't function; nothing visable happens. I am trying to yank members.Name into the page form with autocomplete. It's not working. I don't think I'm even **close** to a solution. Can anyone please help?

## PRELIM

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

## OLD JS ARRAY (which works fine)

```
var players = [ "Addabbo, Eric", "Adeyemon, Murie", "Agok, Peter Panthe", "Ahmed, Jamshed", "Allen, Daniel", "Amato, David Petty"]
```

## OLD JS

```
<script>$(function() {$( ".autocomplete-2" ).autocomplete({delay: 0, source: window.players, minLength: 2, autoFocus: true});});</script>
```

## NEW JSON OBJECT (which doesn't work)

```
var members = 
[
{ "Name": "Ahmed, Jamshed", "cccrEXP": "2018.10.10" },
{ "Name": "Attaya, James", "cccrEXP": "2019.1.12" },
]
```

## NEW JS

```
<script>
$( function() {

$( ".autocomplete-2" ).autocomplete({
  minLength: 0,
  source: members,
  focus: function( event, ui ) {
    $( ".autocomplete-2" ).val( ui.item.label );
    return false;
  },
      return false;
  }
})

} );
</script>
```

Comment: `source: projects,` but your variable seems to be `members`

Comment: Fixed... simple edit. But that doesn't solve the problem, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs for [the Autocomplete Widget](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source) state:

> source:
>
> Defines the data to use, must be specified.
>
> Array: An array can be used for local data. 
>   There are two supported formats:
>
> An array of strings: [ "Choice1", "Choice2" ]
>
> An array of objects **with label and value properties**: [ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ]
>   The label property is displayed in the suggestion menu. The value will be inserted into the input element when a user selects an item.
>   If just one property is specified, it will be used for both, e.g., if
>   you provide only value properties, the value will also be used as the
>   label.

The issue is that your objects don't have the `label` or `value` properties. If you can, change the format of the objects to use those properties. If you can't do that, you could add the needed properties in a loop like so:

```
var members = [{
    "Name": "Ahmed, Jamshed",
    "cccrEXP": "2018.10.10"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Attaya, James",
    "cccrEXP": "2019.1.12"
  },
]

$.each(members, function(i, member){
        member.value = member.label = member.Name; // assuming you want to use .Name for both
});

// now you can pass `members` to the autocomplete method
```

Comment: Please, show the complete code. I am very confused. I don't grok where your code goes.

Comment: BTW my actual object does have the requisite format: http://verlager.com/assets/cccr_mems.json

Comment: I think I got it!

Comment: Absolutely correct. You have saved me several KB of extra json data.